# import face_recognition ImportError: No module named face_recognition in mod_wsgi

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, mod-wsgi, face-recognition

I am trying to deploy my project in mod_wsgi.
**Python : 3.6

Tensorflow 1.14

Flask 1.1.1**

When I created Virtual Environment in python, project run successfully.
Then I am moving to deploy in mod_wsgi. That time its showing below error.

```
import face_recognition  
ImportError: No module named face_recognition
```

**FlaskApp.conf**

```
  <VirtualHost ***.***.***.***:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAdmin test@test.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
```

**flaskapp.wsgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'mykey'
```

if I add package-site manually and modify **flaskapp.wsgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")
sys.path.append('/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Addyoursecretkey'
```

its throwing below error
**ImportError: /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _Py_FalseStruct**

I tried both. How I can deploy my project in mod_wsgi.

Comment: Have you tried to `pip install face_recognition`?

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow yes, in python virtual environment its work.